# ICS FTP - Function to check if folder exists on the ftp server

Tags: delphi, ftp

I'm trying to create a function to check if a folder exists using Overbyte ICS FTP component.Using the DIR command from the icsftp does not display anything in my memo log. 
I'm interested in parsing the result of the dir command into a stringlist in order to search for a specific folder.

For the moment I use an indy function like this. How can I make the same thing with ICS?

```
function exista_textul_in_stringlist(const stringul_pe_care_il_caut:string; stringlistul_in_care_efectuez_cautarea:Tstringlist):boolean;

begin
if stringlistul_in_care_efectuez_cautarea.IndexOf(stringul_pe_care_il_caut) = -1 then
begin
  result:=false;
  //showmessage('Textul "'+text+'" nu exista!' );
end
else
begin

 result:=true;
 //showmessage('Textul "'+text+'" exista la pozitia '+ inttostr(ListBox.Items.IndexOf(text)));
end;
end;

    function folder_exists_in_ftp(folder_name_to_search_for,ftp_hostname,ftp_port,ftp_username,ftp_password,ftp_root_folder:string;memo_loguri:Tmemo):boolean;
    Var
     DirList : TStringList;
     ftp:Tidftp;
     antifreeze:TidAntifreeze;
     var i,k:integer;
    begin
     dateseparator:='-';
     Result := False;
     DirList := TStringList.Create;
     ftp:=tidftp.Create;
     antifreeze:=TidAntifreeze.Create;
     try
        antifreeze.Active:=true;
        ftp.Host:=ftp_hostname;
        ftp.Port:=strtoint(ftp_port);
        ftp.username:=ftp_username;
        ftp.password:=ftp_password;
        ftp.Passive:=true;
        ftp.Connect;

     ftp.ChangeDir(ftp_root_folder);
     ftp.List(DirList, folder_name_to_search_for, True);


      if DirList.Count > 0 then begin
          k := DirList.Count;
          DirList.Clear; // DIRLIST will hold folders only
          for i := 0 to k - 1 do begin
            if (ftp.DirectoryListing.Items[i].FileName <> '.') and (ftp.DirectoryListing.Items[i].FileName <> '..') then begin
              if ftp.DirectoryListing.Items[i].ItemType = ditDirectory then begin
                DirList.Add(ftp.DirectoryListing.Items[i].FileName);
              end;
            end;
          end;
      end;
        if exista_textul_in_stringlist(folder_name_to_search_for,DIRLIST) then
      begin
      Result := True;
      memo_loguri.Lines.Add(datetimetostr(now)+' - caut folderul "'+folder_name_to_search_for+'" in directorul ftp "'+ftp_root_folder+'" => EXISTS!');
      end

      ELSE
      begin
      result:=false;
      memo_loguri.Lines.Add(datetimetostr(now)+' - caut folderul "'+folder_name_to_search_for+'" in directorul ftp "'+ftp_root_folder+'" => NOT exists!');
      end;
     finally
      ftp.Free;
      antifreeze.Free;
      DirList.Free;
     end;

    end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the latest released version of [OverbyteIcs (ICS-V8.16 (Apr, 2015))](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html).

If you just need to check if a remote directory exists its a good recommendation mentioned in the other answer to avoid a list (it could be a time consuming operation if a lot of files and folders are returned).

I suggest you just try to be "optimistic" and change to the remote dir you wish to investigate using `FTP.Cwd`. If this call return true the folder of course exists, and if you plan to continue with the same client you have to change back to the original dir. On the other hand, if the call fails, the directory does not exist if the ftp server reponds with code `550`.

I have included a simple sample doing the above (however, it does not provide the "change-back-to-original-dir-on-success" feature):

```
uses
  ...
  OverbyteIcsFtpCli;

function FtpRemoteDirExists( 
                           HostName: String; 
                           UserName: String; 
                           Password: String; 
                           HostDirToCheck : String ) : Boolean;
const
  cFtpCode_FileOrDirNotExists = 550;
var
  FTP: TFtpClient;
begin
  FTP := TFtpClient.Create(nil);
  try
    FTP.HostName := HostName;
    FTP.Passive := True;
    FTP.Binary := True;
    FTP.Username := UserName;
    FTP.Password := Password;
    FTP.Port := '21';

    if not FTP.Open then
      raise Exception.Create('Failed to connect: ' + FTP.ErrorMessage);

    if (not FTP.User) or (not FTP.Pass) then
      raise Exception.Create('Failed to login: ' + FTP.ErrorMessage);

    FTP.HostDirName := HostDirToCheck;
    if FTP.Cwd then
      Result := True
    else
    begin
      if FTP.StatusCode = cFtpCode_FileOrDirNotExists then
        Result := False
      else
        raise Exception.Create('Failed to change dir: ' + FTP.ErrorMessage);
    end;

  finally
    FTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Excelent solution! The indy function that i posted took about 2 seconds for each querry and parsing based on the amount of files and folders that the ftp had. Your solution is PERFECT! Thank you for helping me!

Comment: @user2858981 nice to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

You better use a command like `SIZE` (`TFtpClient.Size`) or `MLST` (`TFtpClient.Mlst`) to check for file existence.

Using `LIST` is quite an overkill.